# Unity Windows Overlay

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, winapi, user32

I'm trying to make a Overlay for the Windows OS with Unity.
I got all the information, needed for this from this thread in [UnityForum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-windows-transparent-window-with-opaque-contents-lwa_colorkey.323057/).
The script I used is the following:

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class TransparentWindow : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private Material m_Material;
        
        private struct MARGINS
        {
            public int cxLeftWidth;
            public int cxRightWidth;
            public int cyTopHeight;
            public int cyBottomHeight;
        }
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetLayeredWindowAttributes")]
        static extern int SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, int crKey, byte bAlpha, int dwFlags);
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        private static extern int SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, int hwndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);
        
        [DllImport("Dwmapi.dll")]
        private static extern uint DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS margins);
        
        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        const uint WS_POPUP = 0x80000000;
        const uint WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
        
        void Start()
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR // You really don't want to enable this in the editor..
            int fWidth = Screen.width;
            int fHeight = Screen.height;
            var margins = new MARGINS() { cxLeftWidth = -1 };
            var hwnd = GetActiveWindow();
        
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE);
        
            // Transparent windows with click through
            //GWL_EXSTYLE=-20; WS_EX_LAYERED=524288=&h80000, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT=32=0x00000020L
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, -20, 524288 | 32);
            // Transparency=51=20%, LWA_ALPHA=2
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, 2);
            //SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020 (32); //SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040 (64)
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, fWidth, fHeight, 32 | 64); 
            DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, ref margins);
#endif
        }
        
        void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture from, RenderTexture to)
        {
            Graphics.Blit(from, to, m_Material);
        }
    }
```

Now the thing is: The transparency(*works with shader and material*), the Click-through and the alwaysOnTop properties are working perfectly.But, if I click through the window, the application is pausing. How can I implemet, that the program is not pausing while not focused?

Another thing is, that the whole programm just works, if you start it windowed, but not in fullscreen. If i start in fullscreen, it minimizes, when I click something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They might both be related. Unity has an option [`Application.runInBackground`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html)

> Should the player be running when the application is in the background?
>
> Default is `false` (application pauses when it is in the background).

You can enable it in your script like

```
private void Awake()
{
    Application.runInBackground = true;
}
```

or in the Player settings <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Player</kbd> → <kbd>Resolution and Presentation</kbd>

enable <kbd>Run In Background</kbd>

the option <kbd>Visible in Background</kbd> might be interresting for you as well

> Enable this option to show the application in the background if Windowed Fullscreen Mode is used (in Windows).

[image]

Also see the [Standalone Player settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html#Resolution) for more information.

---

General tip:

You should rather wrap the entire `Start` method with

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    private void Start()
    {

    }
#endif
```

If you don't it's not bad but also an empty `Start` method will be called by Unity causing unnecessary overhead.